# How to get rid of Powermock annotations properly?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm migrating my project's tests to JUnit 5 and I want to replace Powermock with Mockito. But in one case I couldn't find out the appropriate equivalents for the following annotations:

```
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class, B.class})
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*",
    "org.w3c.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*", "javax.activation.*", "javax.management.*"})
```

How to replace them properly and what are appropriate equivalents in Mockito?

Comment: can you post more of the actual stuff that is used from PowerMock right now? Probably it will not be sufficient to remove or replace the annotations, but also modifications to the test code might be necessary. A basic precondition is that you have to use minimum Mockito version 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason it used Powermock because Mockito couldn't mock what they need, e.g. final class, constructor, private method...

In order to switch to Mockito without using Powermock or Powermockito, you need to rewrite/redesign your code to be testable. Search how to write testable code, and then you will be able to see the best practices.

Good luck.